# Add a class to element dynamically in a ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following template :

```
<app-subscriber 
  *ngFor="let stream of streams" 
  [stream]="stream" 
  [session]="session" 
  (speakEvents)='onSpeakEvent($event)'>
</app-subscriber>
```

The parent component listens for events from `speakEvents` as so :

```
onSpeakEvent(event: any) {
    if (event.type === 'speaking') {
      this.spotlightSubscriber = event.emitter; 
      //The component emitting the event, from the ngFor repeat list.
      //Add class to this.spotlightSubscriber
    }
    else if (event.type === 'stopped_speaking') {
      //Remove class to this.spotlightSubscriber
    }
  }
```

How can I dynamically add/remove a CSS class to the event emitter, it being in a `*ngFor` loop?

I need to add the class to one element at a time.

Comment: Can you update `streams` using something like `Array.prototype.map()` within `onSpeakEvent()` and set some sort of property/flag on that respective object to use with `ngClass` or similar?

Comment: I see what you mean here, but isn't there a easier solution?

Comment: Setting a property using `map()` on array isn't too involved. The property can be used in an number of ways to add a class or do conditional styling either directly on `*ngFor` or within the `app-subscriber` instance itself.

Comment: @MaximeB - what Alex suggested is way to go for you, what challange or difficulties you're facing there..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two ways of achieving what you're trying to achieve here.

#### Appraoch 1:

Create a property(`indexToAppendClassTo`) to track the indexes which you want to apply the class on. When the event is emitted by the Child Component, add or remove the index of the emitted stream from this `indexToAppendClassTo` list. And apply the class based on the presence of the index of a stream in this `indexToAppendClassTo` list.

In Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  ...
  indexToAppendClassTo: any[] = [];

  onSpeakEvent(event: any, index) {
    // Approach 1
    if (event.type === 'speaking') {
      this.spotlightSubscriber = event.emitter;
      if(this.indexToAppendClassTo.indexOf(index) === -1)
        this.indexToAppendClassTo.push(index);
    } else if (event.type === 'stopped_speaking') {
      if(this.indexToAppendClassTo.indexOf(index) > -1)
        this.indexToAppendClassTo.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<app-subscriber 
  *ngFor="let stream of streams; let i = index;" 
  [stream]="stream" 
  [session]="session" 
  (speakEvents)='onSpeakEvent($event, i)'
  [ngClass]="indexToAppendClassTo.includes(i) ? 'color' : ''">
</app-subscriber>
```

#### Approach 2

As mentioned by others, if you're willing to send some property as a part of the emitted event that decides whether or not to apply the class, then do that from your Child Component and then pass the updated `stream` from the Child as the emitted `$event` data. That way you won't have to unnecessarily manage the `indexToAppendClassTo` list:

In Parent Component Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  ...

  onSpeakEvent(event: any) {
    // Approach 2
    const indexOfElement = this.streams.findIndex(strem => strem.name === event.name);
    this.streams[indexOfElement] = { ...event };
  }
}
```

In Parent Component Template:

```
<app-subscriber 
  *ngFor="let stream of streams" 
  [stream]="stream" 
  [session]="session" 
  (speakEvents)='onSpeakEvent($event)'
  [ngClass]="stream.type === 'speaking' ? 'color': ''">
</app-subscriber>
```

And In Child Component Class:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-subscriber',
  templateUrl: './subscriber.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./subscriber.component.css']
})
export class SubscriberComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() stream;
  @Input() session;
  @Output() speakEvents: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  ...

  onClick() {
    this.speakEvents.emit({ ...this.stream, type: 'type of the stream here' });
  }

  ...

}
```

And in Child Component Template:

```
<button (click)="onClick()">{{stream.name}}</button>
```

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stream-list-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) with both the appraoches for your ref.

Comment: Note: If the streams change (ie: new or removed stream), the wrong ones will have the class since the only thing used to track them is the index. If that's a problem for OP, you might want to track some kind of unique identifier instead of an index, if that is available. You would then use say `stream.streamId` everywhere instead of `i`.

Comment: Yeah or you could have a `hasClass` property on each stream object. So instead of passing in the index, you pass in the `stream` itself and set the property.

Comment: That's an improvement, but it doesn't fix if things are added or removed from `streams`. I think that's ok - we don't have enough information to see what would need to be done if `streams` change -  so I think your solution is good. Was gonna comment on `appendClass`, but you fixed it :)